# Como hacer un spinner numerico en java?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando hacer un spinner con puros numeros (1,2,3,4,5 etc) a estos los agrego a un arraylist en un ciclo for

```
    List<Integer> numb = new ArrayList<Integer>();
spMov = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.SpinMov);
    for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++) {
            numb.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numb);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spMov.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Pero al abrir el layout me cierra la aplicacion

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
> null object reference

se que se puede hacer con un array en el xml pero la verdad siento que es mas rentable asi, asi si solo quiero aumentar el valor.. solo aumento en el for

Comment: Te está diciendo que en esta línea `spMov.setAdapter(dataAdapter);` spMov es null, has hecho un `findViewById()` primero para asignar spMov??

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu pronta respuesta, si asi es asigne con el findViewById

Comment: Pues prueba a imprimirlo a ver qué te dice, porque según ese error, es `null`, eso significa que no lo ha encontrado

Comment: Listo pude solucionarlo !

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que pongas la solución en una respuesta y la aceptes :)

Comment: MI error fue no agregar el final al principio del Array 
final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numb);

Answer (score 0):

El error fue sencillo para mi, si ha alguien le ha ayuda con gusto

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView NumTractor = root.findViewById(R.id.txtTractor);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        });

        spMov = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.SpinMov);

        for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++) {
            numb.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        Log.d("mensaje", numb.toString());

        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numb);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spMov.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

       

        return root;
    }
```

De esta manera tienes un spinner numerico en un ciclo for